# Recursive Algorithm Effiency - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, performance

I'm working on a coding project, and I am having a problem with the speed of the program. The program takes an input between 1 and 80, this input represents a number of match sticks, and outputs how many different numbers can be made with that number of match sticks.

Ex: The number 1 can be formed with 2 match sticks, and the number 2 requires 5 match sticks

Here is the full prompt of the program:

[image: prompt of program]

Here is my code to the algorithm I came up with to compute all the possible out comes, it functions fairly well for the lower end of the inputs although it becomes highly inefficient for large inputs such as 80 taking hours to compute all the possibilities. How can I cut this time down to a minimum?

n represents the input, and all the Counter object does is keep track of each possible number created

```
public static void digitCounter(int n, Counter count) {
    if (n < 2) {
        //ouput
    } else {
        if (count.getCount() == 0) {

            // If there are enough match sticks to form it
            // accounts for 0 only once
            if (n >= 7) {
                // counts 0
                count.setCount(10);
                // counts 1
                digitCounter(n - 2, count);
                // counts 2
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                // counts 3
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                // count 4
                digitCounter(n - 4, count);
                // counts 5
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                // counts 6
                digitCounter(n - 6, count);
                // counts 7
                digitCounter(n - 3, count);
                // counts 8
                digitCounter(n - 7, count);
                // counts 9
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
            } else if (n == 6) {
                count.setCount(9);
                digitCounter(n - 2, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 4, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 6, count);
                digitCounter(n - 3, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
            } else if (n == 5) {
                count.setCount(7);
                digitCounter(n - 2, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 4, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 3, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
            } else if (n == 4) {
                count.setCount(3);
                digitCounter(n - 2, count);
                digitCounter(n - 4, count);
                digitCounter(n - 3, count);
            } else if (n == 3) {
                count.setCount(2);
                digitCounter(n - 2, count);
                digitCounter(n - 3, count);
            } else if (n == 2) {
                count.setCount(1);
                digitCounter(n - 2, count);
            }
        }

        // Accounts for every other number after 0 is accounted for so
        // numbers with leading 0's are not formed
        // Ex: 001 is illegal
        else {
            if (n >= 7) {
                count.setCount(count.getCount() + 10);
                digitCounter(n - 6, count);
                digitCounter(n - 2, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 4, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 6, count);
                digitCounter(n - 3, count);
                digitCounter(n - 7, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
            } else if (n == 6) {
                count.setCount(count.getCount() + 9);
                digitCounter(n - 6, count);
                digitCounter(n - 2, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 4, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 6, count);
                digitCounter(n - 3, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
            } else if (n == 5) {
                count.setCount(count.getCount() + 7);
                digitCounter(n - 2, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 4, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
                digitCounter(n - 3, count);
                digitCounter(n - 5, count);
            } else if (n == 4) {
                count.setCount(count.getCount() + 3);
                digitCounter(n - 2, count);
                digitCounter(n - 4, count);
                digitCounter(n - 3, count);
            } else if (n == 3) {
                count.setCount(count.getCount() + 2);
                digitCounter(n - 2, count);
                digitCounter(n - 3, count);
            } else if (n == 2) {
                count.setCount(count.getCount() + 1);
                digitCounter(n - 2, count);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So many of your cases call `digitCounter(n-5, count)` multiple times. Do you expect the result to be different the second, third or fourth time you call it?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you're using `count` instead of a return value.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to solve your own problem before coming to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

What if you modified your design so that `digitCounter(n)` *returned* the count of numbers that could be formed by `n` toothpicks, and then cache that value in a persistent map? On entry to `digitCounter` check your map and return the cached value if you have already calculated it once.. Then you would still have a recursive algorithm, but it would not need to make repetitive calls for the same N.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply the number of solutions you get with a given number of matches. You can also cache the number of solutions up to a give number.

```
public static long solutionsFor(int matchCount) {
    long[] counts = new long[matchCount+1];
    for(int i = 0; i <= matchCount; i++) {
       long count = ... calculate count based on previous values ...
       counts[i] = count;
    }
    return counts[matchCount];
}
```

The performance gain is that the cost is O(n) and you are likely to get your answer in a few milli-seconds for the largest problems which return a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that one call of `digitCounter` can spawn up to 10 calls to `digitCounter` which can spawn even more calls to it. So your first try to optimize would be to reduce the number off calls.

@pamphlet asked:

> So many of your cases call digitCounter(n-5, count) multiple times. Do
>   you expect the result to be different the second, third or fourth time
>   you call it?

This should be your first clue to optimize. The actual count that you add to your counter should be the same every time you call `digitCounter(n-5, count)`. So I would suggest you let digit counter return the count directly and add it yourself. To signify whether to count 0 or not, add a flag that indicates whether it is the topmost call to `digitCounter` or not.

Call `digitCounter` with n=10.

for `count=0` you will end up in the following code (comments removed)

```
        if (n >= 7) {
            count.setCount(10);
            digitCounter(n - 2, count);
            digitCounter(n - 5, count);
            digitCounter(n - 5, count);
            digitCounter(n - 4, count);
            digitCounter(n - 5, count);
            digitCounter(n - 6, count);
            digitCounter(n - 3, count);
            digitCounter(n - 7, count);
            digitCounter(n - 5, count);
        } else if (n == 6) {
```

you effective call

1x `digitCounter(n - 2, count);`

1x `digitCounter(n - 3, count);`

1x `digitCounter(n - 4, count);`

4x `digitCounter(n - 5, count);`

1x `digitCounter(n - 6, count);`

1x `digitCounter(n - 7, count);`

Calling `digitCounter(n - 5, count);` which is `digitCounter(5, count);` for n = 10 results in additial 10 calls to `digitCounter`. so by calling it once instead of 4 time you save 3x(1+10)=33 calls.

Another optimization is saving the last call that you do. You know the result for `digitCounter(0)` is 0. So why do you try to compute it?

```
        } else if (n == 2) {
            count.setCount(count.getCount() + 1);
            digitCounter(n - 2, count);
        }
```

can be rewritten to

```
        } else if (n == 2) {
            count.setCount(count.getCount() + 1);
            digitCounter(2 - 2, count);
        }
```

so you can remove the call `digitCounter(2 - 2, count);` since it doesn't impact your results. Likewise, the result for `digitCounter(1)` is 0. So after optimizing the case `n=3` we removed 2 more unnecessary calls. `digitCounter(2)` is always 1. So for `n=4` you can remove 3 unnecessary calls, just increase your counter by 4 instead of 3.

you can also optimize `n=5` the same way. `digitCounter(3)` is always 2. So you can eliminate 7 additional calls and increase the counter by 10 instead of just 7. I let you optimize the case `n=6` for yourself.

This should already result in a big reduction of recursive calls. It might seem to be minimal but it adds up fast.

The next optimization would be caching as suggested by @JVMATL you can gain massive savings for big N. The call for `digitCounter(n-2)` will result in call for `digitCounter((n-2) -2)` which is equivalent to `digitCounter(n-4)`. So you don't need to calculate the value again, which results in huge savings for big n (like `n=80`). Even though caching might not help you for small n and might even increase the runtime (who cares about milliseconds anyway) you have a big gain for big n (reaches easily seconds/minutes).